# Water is not comming out from tap

Tags: plumbing-fixture

Our house is not in being used for years. Only one person is living and using only one washroom. Now we don't have water coming out from taps in other unused areas of house. Really appreciate your suggestion. House is in hot area so no issue of frozen pipe.

Comment: Check the aerators on the faucets and make sure any shutoff valves are turned on...

Comment: Has the house been extended?  There may be internal shut-off valves which someone closed in the past and have since forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

If your pipes are not copper or are galvanized there could be blockage due to interior of pipe rusting/corroding. With that in mind, check your faucet aerator for restrictions made from debris build-up. It would be wise to invest in a [water pressure gauge](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T58JMTJ) so as to check pressure at several locations. Most household water pressure is between 60 and 70 psi. Also look for forgotten/hidden valves that are partially open.